# Thymeleaf call custom java class without spring boot

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have class Utils

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.*;

public class Utils {
    public static Comparator getComparatorByTwoFields(String key1, String key2) {
        return new Comparator<Map<String, Object>>() {
            public int compare(Map<String, Object> m1, Map<String, Object> m2) {
                int firstCompare = ((String) m1.get(key1)).compareTo((String) m2.get(key1));
                if (firstCompare == 0) {
                    return ((String) m1.get(key2)).compareTo((String) m2.get(key2));
                }
                return firstCompare;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And I want to add comparator when I sort list inside thymeleaf like this:

```
<th:block th:with="sortedItems = ${#lists.sort(items, @com.example.test.Utils@getComparatorByTwoFields('name', 'age'))}">
```

But I get an Exception: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to resolve class: com.example.test.Utils

What should be done to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of explicitly referencing the comparator's class name in Thymeleaf, you can simply pass the comparator object into your model, in the same way that you pass other objects.

For example, assuming you have your `items` list:

```
model.put("items", items);
```

And then you also need:

```
model.put("myComparator", Utils.getComparatorByTwoFields("name", "age"));
```

Then in your Thymeleaf:

```
<th:blockth:with="sortedItems = ${#lists.sort(items, myComparator)}">
```

**Two Notes**

1. The comparator in your question is expecting to compare two `Map` objects - so I am not sure what your `List` of items looks like. It would need to be a list of maps for the comparator to actually work, the way it is written.
2. You could just sort the list before you pass it to the Thymeleaf template. I think that would be a bit cleaner - but that is purely a matter of personal choice.